# Como criar métodos de extensão no Entity Framework usando Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

É possível criar métodos de extensão personalizados para o Linq to entities?

No projeto que eu trabalho, por exemplo, temos diversas colunas de tipo `DateTimeOffset?`. Em determinadas views eu preciso filtrar os resultados pela data, então faço o seguinte:

```
var teste = DateTime.Today;
var bars = this._barRepository.All();
bars = bars.Where(b => b.DataInicio.Value.Day == teste.Day && b.DataInicio.Value.Month == 
                 teste.DataInicio.Month && b.DataInicio.Value.Year == teste.Year).ToList();
```

É possível criar um método de extensão para que eu não precise comparar dia, mês e ano todas as vezes?

O que eu tentei criar:

```
public static bool SameDate(this DateTimeOffset? source, DateTime? date)
{
    if(!source.HasValue || !date.HasValue)
        return false;

    return source.Value.Day == date.Value.Day && source.Value.Month == 
        date.Value.Month && source.Value.Year ==date.Value.Year;
}
```

Mas ele me lança a exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'bool SameDate'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Achei algumas respostas no SOen dizendo para usar `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`, mas eu queria criar minhas próprias extensões - se isso for possível.

Comment: Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta e postar como criou. Aí podermos ver onde está errando.

Comment: Amigo, você está aplicando um `All` na base e depois aplica o `Where`? Isso está fazendo você trazer todas as informações da base e depois filtrando em memória, não lhe recomendo fazer isto.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura O All() desse repositório retorna um Queryable.

Comment: @EduardoMoreira ah, tudo bem então ;)

Comment: Agora entendi melhor o seu problema... eu consigo pensar em duas soluções, mas não posso fazer agora, não tenho recursos no momento, em casa se ninguém te ajudar eu edito minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É possível criar métodos de extensão personalizados para o Linq to entities?

Sim, mas isso é um pouco complexo. Vou explicar as linhas-guia de como fazer isso.

O Linq to Entities traduz cada método de extensão em um predicado de acordo com o *provider*, ou seja, se faço um `Where()`, o *provider* SQL Server irá traduzir a extensão para o SQL com a melhor compatibilidade possível para o SQL Server. O *provider* MySQL fará a mesma coisa para o MySQL, e assim por diante.

Portanto, a maneira correta de interceder no processo de geração do SQL é reimplementando o `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
public class QueryTranslatorProvider<T> : ExpressionVisitor, IQueryProvider
{
    internal IQueryable source;

    public QueryTranslatorProvider(IQueryable source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        this.source = source;
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        return new QueryTranslator<TElement>(source, expression) as IQueryable<TElement>;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        Type elementType = expression.Type.GetGenericArguments().First();
        IQueryable result = (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(QueryTranslator<>).MakeGenericType(elementType),
            new object[] { source, expression });
        return result;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        object result = (this as IQueryProvider).Execute(expression);
        return (TResult)result;
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        Expression translated = this.Visit(expression);
        return source.Provider.Execute(translated);
    }

    internal IEnumerable ExecuteEnumerable(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        Expression translated = this.Visit(expression);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(translated);
    }

    #region Visitors
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        // fix up the Expression tree to work with EF again
        if (c.Type == typeof(QueryTranslator<T>))
        {
            return source.Expression;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitConstant(c);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

E depois, implementar seu `SameDate` dentro de um `IOrderedQueryable<T>`:

```
public class QueryTranslator<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    private Expression expression = null;
    private QueryTranslatorProvider<T> provider = null;

    public QueryTranslator(IQueryable source)
    {
        expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        provider = new QueryTranslatorProvider<T>(source);
    }

    public QueryTranslator(IQueryable source, Expression e)
    {
        if (e == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
        expression = e;
        provider = new QueryTranslatorProvider<T>(source);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)provider.ExecuteEnumerable(this.expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return provider.ExecuteEnumerable(this.expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public QueryTranslator<T> SameDate(DateTimeOffset? source, DateTime? date) 
    {
        // Implemente aqui
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return provider; }
    }
}
```

Dentro dele, você pode criar seus próprios métodos de extensão, interceptando corretamente as chamadas para o *provider* do banco de dados. [A ideia geral está aqui (pergunta e respostas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839901/how-to-wrap-entity-framework-to-intercept-the-linq-expression-just-before-executi).

Comment: +1 bom saber dessa

Answer (score 2):

Sim, tem como fazer isto. O próprio `Where` do `IQueryable` na verdade é um método de extensão, na verdade, maior parte dos filtros que se tem em `IEnumerable` e `IQueryable` são métodos de extensão. Por isso que você precisa adicionar `using System.Linq` no seu código, para que os métodos de extensão sejam capturados. No seu caso, basta criar um método como abaixo e adicionar o comportamento desejado:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> SeuFiltroAqui<TSource>(
  this IQueryable<TSource> source,
  DateTime date
)
```

### Importante

1 - se você não aplicar isso encima do `IQueryable` e sim encima do `IEnumerable`, as consultas vão ser feitas na memória, então use `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2):

Veja o exemplo abaixo de como você pode criar um método de extensão como você quer.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class BuscarProdutos : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
            {
                var query = ctx.Produto

                    // métod de extesão para Where
                    .Where_Produto(DateTime.Today)

                    // métod de extesão para criação de uma view
                    .Vw_Produto(ctx)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class cvw_Produto
    {
        public SubCategoria produto { get; internal set; }
        public string Descricao { get; internal set; }
        public int? Estoque { get; internal set; }
        public decimal? Preco { get; internal set; }
        public int ProdutoId { get; internal set; }
    }

    public static class ProdutoExt
    {
        public static IQueryable<Produto> Where_Produto(
                this IQueryable<Produto> qrIn, DateTime? teste)
        {
            if (teste == null)
                return qrIn;

            return qrIn
                .Where(b => b.DataInicio.Value.Day == teste.Value.Day &&
                b.DataInicio.Value.Month == teste.Value.Month && b.DataInicio.Value.Year == teste.Value.Year);
        }


        // aqui você ainda pode fazer views como a abaixo
        public static IQueryable<cvw_Produto> Vw_Produto(
                this IQueryable<Produto> qrIn, stackoverflowEntities ctx)
        {
            return qrIn
                .Select(p => new cvw_Produto 
                {
                    // você pode usar para fazer select em outras tabelas que tem relação com a tabela passada no parametro. IQueryable<Produto> qrIn
                    produto = ctx.SubCategoria.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.CategoriaId == p.ProdutoId),
                    ProdutoId = p.ProdutoId,
                    Descricao = p.Descricao,
                    Preco = p.Preco,
                    Estoque = p.Estoque
                });
        }
    }
}
```